# How to upload to store version for Windows Phone 8.0 with existing version for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I have built application for Windows Phone 8.1 and upload it to Store.

Now I created version for Windows Phone 8.0

Can I have them as one application in Store?

And if so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app that has different versions for Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 but is visible as one in Store. I hope it works for Windows Phone 8.1 as well.

Log in to your **Dev Center** account and open your app details page. Click **Update app**, then go to **Upload and describe your package(s)** section. And here's the point. Instead of replacing the existing package, just click **Add new**. You'll have two packages, but it will be one app in Store. Windows Phone 8 users should see the new version you want to upload and Windows Phone 8.1 users will have the old one without changes. None of them would see both version.

Comment: Worked as promised. Thank you))